# Jenkins pipeline - building parallel with map received from function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Recently I have tried to build a jenkins pipeline with a large number of 'Tests' in one of its stages.

The thing is, at some point I got an error regarding my stages phase was too large, so I tried to solve it with function that will build all of my stages and I can run this function output(map of stages) in parallel.
Some of the stages have to run on agent(node) taken from a label, and others have some unique steps in them.
I am trying to understand in general, how can I write a function that will build a map to run in parallel - but was not successfull nor did I found any good example of it online.

I know the question is general, but if anyone can point me to some examples, or just write one, it will be great.

This is the snippet I am working on(not full JenkinsFile):

```
def getParallelBuilders(list_arr) {

def builders = [:]   

builders['Test-1'] = 
            stage ('Test-1')
            {
                node('ci-nodes')
                {
                        when {
                            environment name: 'TEST_NAME', value: 'true'
                            beforeAgent true
                        }
                        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
                        script { runtests() }
                        post {
                            success { onTestSuccess title: 'Temp', pytest: 'results.xml' }
                            cleanup { afterTestCleanup2("clean") }
                        }
                }
            }
return builders
```

}

The call to this function happens from my 'pipeline' block, after stages of build, configure etc:

```
        stage('Testing') {
            steps {
                script { parallel getParallelBuilders(list_arr) }
            }
        }
```

Not sure if my approach to this problem is right at all, 
hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, here is the solution I got for my problem:

```
    builders = [
            'Test1':
            {
                stage ('Test1')
                {
                    if (RUN_TESTS == 'true')
                    {
                        timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES')
                        {
                            node('ci-nodes')
                            {
                                try 
                                {
                                    runtests()
                                    onTestSuccess title: 'Temp', pytest: 'results.xml'
                                } 
                                catch (err)
                                {
                                    onTestFailure testName: "Test1"
                                }
                                finally 
                                {
                                    afterTestCleanup()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The main issue was understanding the scripting pipeline syntax, which is really diffrent fron the declarative way.